# Como formatear un Json en PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Veran estoy teniendo problemas para enviar información a una API, en si el problema es que me envía la información como un String y por lo tanto no funciona el recorrido del arreglo.

Lo que yo deseo recibir es algo así:

```
{"datos":["83","3"],"mail":"adanasr@gmail.com"}
```

Pero lo que estoy recibiendo es esto:

```
{"datos":"[\"83\",\"3\"]","mail":"adanasr@gmail.com"}
```

¿Como puedo formatear dicho string con PHP para lograr el resultado esperado?

Gracias.

Comment: puedes publicar la parte en la que tienes la codificacion a cadena? aparentemente no estas codificando correctamente a json. Lo correcto seria utilizar `json_decode` y `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos enviados a un api yo suelo hacer esto, así cargo toda la información en una variable llamada "data"

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Fuente: Experiencia propia